# Capture using uiautomatorviewer on a virtual android device

Tags: android, appium, uiautomatorviewer

I have my appium setup on Windows virtual machine and since Virtual Box do not support nested virtualization I created an Android emulator on Virtual Box and connected the two virtual machines. I am able to launch the app on virtual android emulator.

So my issue is that `uiautomatorviewer` is unable to capture the screenshot. Error message says `Error taking device screenshot: EOF`. Please help me with the issue.

I checked via `adb devices`, that two devices are connected to each other. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Stop Appium server and kill & restart adb server.

**adb kill-server**

**adb start-server**

then try to get the screenshot or identify the DOM elements. Hope it helps!